# How to load a CSS file from a URL?

Tags: theming, 10

I have a raw github page with CSS:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPOSITORY/main/website/style.css
```

How to load it in my website to effect the website globally?

I tried this in `/core/themes/olivero/olivero.libraries.yml` but no change occured after cache rebuild.

```
global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      css/base/fonts.css: {}
      css/base/base.css: {}
      css/base/utility.css: {}
      css/base/https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/REPOSITORY/main/website/style.css: {}
```

Comment: @Hudri I am not sure because I don't want to do it for a module, rather globally, for all the website. I have also tried something on `olivero.libraries.yml` that didn't work. I'll edit to expand.

Comment: I have edited because I believe my question is unrelated to module development, rather, to core customization.

Comment: Simple rule: Never edit core. Create a custom theme or a custom module, both will do for this usecase.

Comment: I am well aware of that rule :) I never edit core unless it's one line about CSS or one line about JS. This is indeed my need here.

Comment: You either loose the ability to upgrade or your changes break at the next update. does not matter if it is 1 line or 1000.

Comment: @Hudri correct but if, with each upgrade, I inject the same new line somehow, yes, it's "corky" but works.

Comment: @themer Most of all, it's not necessary to change core files. There are simple and well documented ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

External files can be used, but for a CSS file the definition is similar to the following one.

```yaml
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css: { type: external, minified: true }
```

`type: external` is necessary to make Drupal know that is an external file; `minified: true` is used only when the file is minified.

As comments already said, it is a bad idea to change a Drupal core file because those changes are lost all the times Drupal is updated. Instead, it is better to create a custom theme, which can also use the core theme as parent theme.

Comment: I can't get the file to load. I have updated about how I use the link.

Comment: Questions cannot be edited, if they invalidate the given answers. They are not for a back-and-forth with the users who answer them.

Comment: Okay then I guess I should ask a new question.